# Dynamic case statement in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, bash-completion

I'm trying to figure out how to create a dynamic case statement in a bash script.

For example, let's say I have the output of an awk statement with the following contents

```
red
green
blue
```

In this scenario, the output can change at any time.

I'm trying to then execute different logic if a value is included in this awk output.

So if the data above is in $list, then I'd conceptually like to do something like:

```
case "${my_var}" in
    $list)
        .....
    something_else)
        .....
esac
```

I'm trying to use this to build a dynamic custom tab completion function (see http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2 for some background).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The interesting question is: "how are you going to specify what goes in the ..... part of the case for each of the actions?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` statement is probably not the right tool for the job. If you store the `awk` output in an array then you can loop through the array to find if a choice is in it, and as a bonus can figure out which index that is, too.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Store command output in an array so each word is a separate array item.    
list=($(echo $'red\ngreen\nblue'))
my_var=blue

for ((i = 0; i < ${#list}; i++)); do
    if [[ ${list[$i]} = $my_var ]]; then
        echo "found at index $i"
        break
    fi
done

if ((i == ${#list})); then
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a dynamic case statement in bash by doing the following:

1) ensure the list is PIPE (|) seperated. IE.  red|green|blue

2) wrap your case statement in an eval

For example:

```
valid="red|green|blue"

eval "case \"$choice\" in
    $valid)
        echo do something good here
        ;;
    *)
        echo invalid colour
        ;;
esac"
```

This works for simple variable processing, I can not guarantee this will work in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a case statement, but it's easy enough to set up your own helper to check for list membership.

```
# stub to simulate this arbitrary call
my_awk_command() { printf '%s\n' red green blue; }
# helper to check list membership
list_contains() {
  local tgt="$1"; shift
  while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = "$tgt" ]] ; then
      return 0
    fi
    shift
  done
  return 1
}

# the below is Bash 4 functionality; see BashFAQ #1 on how to replace it
readarray -t awk_output < <(my_awk_command)

if list_contains "$my_var" "${my_awk_command[@]}"; then
  ...something...
elif [[ "$my_var" = something_else ]] ; then
  ...something else...
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple to manage with the standard tools available in bash 4. The size of array OptionList can vary freely.

```
OptionList=(Fred Wilma Barney)
PS3='Choose a character : '
select opt in "${OptionList[@]}" "Quit"; do
    case "$REPLY" in
        $((${#OptionList[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; exit;;
    esac
    [ $REPLY -gt $((${#OptionList[@]}+1)) -o $REPLY -lt 1 ] && echo "Invalid selection" || break
done

echo "you chose ${OptionList[(($REPLY-1))]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this in a couple of different hacky ways:

```
pattern=($(awk_command))     # red\ngreen\nblue\n
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
pattern="^(${pattern[*]})$"  # ^(red|green|blue)$  (perhaps hackish)
IFS=$saveIFS

# simple regex match if statement (not hackish)
if [[ $var =~ $pattern ]]
then
    do_something
fi

# or a backwards case statement (very hackish)
case 1 in    # this could be a variable or a command substitution
    $([[ $var =~ $pattern]] && echo 1) )  # the echo 1 could be another command or the 1 could be yet another variable
        do_something;;
    * )
        do_default;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

might you have to try,
sorry if this might to be oot/didnt you guys looking for, (but i think it's help me out)
here i have same issues to using wheter sh case with dynamic statement

whereas i have running some function with dynamic listed parameter as input
then if there's no function inside/available, it will return exit 1 or "requested not available"

here we go.

```
myfuncA(){
   echo this funcA
}

myfuncB(){
   echo this funcB
}


dynamicCase(){
   for areWe in $1; do
      my$areWe && echo "$areWe success" || echo "no function $1 available"
   done
}

anotherDyCase(){
   while IFS=read -r $areWe; do
      my$areWe && echo "$areWe success" || echo "no function $1 "
   done <<< $1
}
```

test ride:

```
myListedDynamic="funcA\nfuncB\nfuncC"
// funcA funcB funcC


dynamicCase $myListedDynamic
// success
// success
// no function available
```

[furthermore](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/#:%7E:text=For%20the%20bash%20shell%27s%20purposes,the%20return%20status%20is%20126.)

hope help

Answer (score 0):

Cross posted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411001/using-case-and-arrays-together-in-bash/718391#718391)...

For recent versions of `bash`, you can use the non-short-circuiting `;;&` operator; it's not `case` directly supporting arrays in its clauses, but it's reasonably elegant:

```
ARR=( opt1 opt2 opt3 );

case $1 in
    *)
        [[ ${ARR[*]} =~ $1 ]] \
            && echo "Option is contained in the array" \
            && exit 0
        ;;&

    *)
        echo "Option is not contained in the array"
        ;;
esac
```

Note `;;&` (i.e. non-short circuiting) ensures the `$1` is evaluated against subsequent case-clauses; this requires the `exit 0` (use `return 0` in a function/sourced file) to skip subsequent