# Is it possible to generate dynamic patterns for case statement in Bash?

Tags: bash, case-statement

For example,

```
a="1|2|3"
b=3
case $b in
$a )
echo in
;;
* )
echo out
;;
*)
esac
```

I'd like `$a` to be expanded as `1|2|3`. But seems it cannot work as expected. Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: take a look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687722/dynamic-case-statement-in-bash

Comment: Solvable via extglob: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13254908/1030675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `|` is not part of the pattern, but part of the `case` statement's syntax that separates two patterns. The following would work:

```
foo=3
b1=1
b2=2
b3=3

case $foo in
    $b1|$b2|$b3) echo match ;;
esac
```

The `|` needs to be visible to the parser before parameter expansion occurs to act as a pattern separator. If the `|` is produced by a parameter expansion, it is treated as a literal character to match as part of a pattern.

Comment: A `case $b in +($a) ) echo in ;; ` also works correctly provided that a `shopt -s extglob` is in effect.

Comment: Yeah, I considered adding a note about that when I saw @choroba's comment, but then decided to just explain why placing a bar in a parameter alone didn't work.